# iOS: How do RSS links work - only able to get link, title and description?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, swift3, rss

Alright, new to RSS Parsing here but I am working off a generic GitHub implementation of an RSS parser trying to get an m4a off an RSS publisher - Libsyn. 
According to https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html RSS feeds can be embedded with tags (described in the Elements of  part of that link)

The implementation I have takes the link and just displays it in a new view:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    if isTagFound["title"] == true {
        self.rssRecord?.title += string

    } else if isTagFound["link"] == true {
        self.rssRecord?.link += string

    } else if isTagFound["pubDate"] == true {
        self.rssRecord?.pubDate += string            

    } else if isTagFound["category"] == true {
        self.rssRecord?.category += string
    }    
}    

// element end detected
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == "item" {
        self.isTagFound["item"] = false
        self.rssRecordList.append(self.rssRecord!)

    } else if elementName == "title" {
        self.isTagFound["title"] = false

    } else if elementName == "link" {
        self.isTagFound["link"] = false

        // find index path for selected row
        let selectedIndexPath : [IndexPath] = self.myTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!

        // deselect the selected row
        self.myTableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath[0], animated: true)

        // create destination view controller
        let destVc = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController

        // set title for next screen
        destVc.navigationItem.title = self.rssRecordList[selectedIndexPath[0].row].title

        // set link value for destination view controller
        destVc.link = self.rssRecordList[selectedIndexPath[0].row].link /
```

While this link has an m4a attached to it as well as other attributes, it seems I am only able to get the following tags: link, pubDate, title, item so that I can print them to console.

I having difficulty understanding this - the item is the RSS "block" itself, however while the page clearly has a category at the bottom with the following:

```
else if isTagFound["category"] == true {
    self.rssRecord?.category += string
}
```

then

```
 print("CATEGORY: ",self.rssRecordList[selectedIndexPath[0].row].category)
```

I get nothing. How does one get other tags? If just a file (m4a) is published to something like Libsyn and the link leads directly to the m4a (not this kind of page), is it still possible to get other tags like "category?"

Currently:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of an RSS feed that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Sure - http://aidpodcast.libsyn.com/rss

Comment: Note that in the feed, "category" is a child of the "channel" element, not a child of each "item" element.  So, you would need to find the "category" elements, remembering to extract the value you need as an attribute and not the text within the tag, then squirrel it away.  Here's a hint: you're creating a new rssRecord when you encounter an "item" tag.  Think of the doc as top down, and you'll see that you've encountered the "category" tags  well before you encounter the first "item" tag, so no rssRecord object exists yet.

Comment: Oh.. thank you that makes it a lot clearer actually. Would you provide some example code for getting both the item and the channel elements in an answer so I can accept it?